# Как добавить Materialize Modal с HAML?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

Необходимо добавить всплывающее окно Modal, но не могу разобраться как это сделать с haml. Сейчас включается modal trigger, но показывает пустой экран с характерным затемнением.

haml:

```
%a.modal-trigger{:href => 'modal1'} Modal

#modal1.modal
  .modal-content
    %h4 Modal Header
    %p Modal text
```

js:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

Comment: А на HTML получилось?

Comment: Да, работает нормально.

Comment: Так сравните разметку что ли :D

Comment: Все, понял, я пропустил нюанс когда перекидывал в haml. В оригинале #modal1, а я без "#" написал)) Спасибо.

Comment: И вновь триумф отладки :D